# Real, analytic exponential factorial $f(x) = x^{f(x-1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-equations, analytic-functions

I'm wondering if anyone has a reference or a method for construction a real-analytic function interpolating the [exponential factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_factorial), i.e. a function such that $f(x) = x^{f(x-1)}$ and $f(1) = 1$, analogous to the gamma function interpolating the usual factorial.

It's easy to construct a complex-valued solution that should be analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ to the clearly related functional equation $f(z) = z^{(z-1)^{(z-2)^{f(z-3)}}}$ (note that satisfying the exponential factorial equation implies this, but not the other way around). If you look at the power tower $$
f_n(z) =z^{(z-1)^{(z-2)^{(z-3)^{\cdots (z-n)}}}}
$$
the values have period 3 as $n$ approaches infinity, so it seems reasonable that there are 3 limiting analytic functions, each satisfying $f(z)=z^{(z-1)^{(z-2)^{f(z-3)}}}$. (I haven't proven any of this formally, since I was mostly trying to find a real-valued solution and these are not real valued on $\mathbb{R}$) An example computation, here's a plot of the real and imaginary parts of $f_n(1.5)$ for $n$ from 0 to 100 (real part in black, imaginary part in red):[image: plot_of_fn]

$f_{3n}$ seems to converge pretty rapidly (and similarly for $f_{3n+1}$ and $f_{3n+2}$). But these limiting functions won't be analytic at integer values; in general it will only be $n-1$ times differentiable at $n\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Also, I don't believe they would have the property $f(x)=x^{f(x-1)}$ because of the 3-period nature of the limit.

Does anyone know of a way to construct a real-analytic solution to the equation, or at least a solution that is analytic (but possibly complex-valued) on $\mathbb{R}$?

If it's easier to solve the equation $f(x) = x^{f(x-1)}$ with a different initial value, i.e. $f(1) = c$ for some other value of $c$, I would also be interested to see that.

Comment: What should $f(1.5)$ be using this definition ? There is no stopping rule to determine this value.

Comment: There are three limit points of $f_n(1.5)$, which are approximately $1.04 - 0.03i$, $1.75 - 0.134i$, and $0.742 - 0.205i$.

Comment: So, you mean $n-1$ in the exponent instead of $x-1$ ? If so, we basically get the concept of tetration.

Comment: No, those are the limit points of $1.5^{0.5^{(-0.5)^{(-1.5)^{\cdots^{1.5-n}}}}}$.

Comment: I've updated the question, now with a picture. Hopefully it's clearly what $f_n(z)$ is doing.

Comment: I doubt that such continuation exists or could be defined. Roughly speaking, in gamma function we use the integral and exponential function to interpolate the notion of consequent multiplying. For this exponential factorial, it seems we will need some new tools. The integral is itself a kind of _addition_, so this new tool has to incorporate some equivalent operator that is an extension to _multiplication_. Hope you get what I am trying to say...

Comment: "Exists" and "could be defined" are two different questions; I'm interested in both. I wouldn't be as pessimistic, analytic functions are pretty flexible. In my mind the main difficulty is the singularity at 0.

Comment: @polfosol If what you were suggesting is using a product integral, I have tried that but with no success. I would also accept an answer proving non-existence (though that would surprise me)